# i have a problem with Array to string conversion

Tags: arrays, laravel

I am trying to insert data into a database table but unfortunately, I am facing an error please help me how can I resolve this issue?

request here https://ibb.co/v3ZKkyC

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'icon' => 'required',
        'image_gallery' => 'required',
        'heading' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'location' => 'required',
        'detail' => 'required',
    ]);

    foreach ($request->image_gallery as $key => $value) {
        SMEvent::create([
            'icon' => $request->icon,
            'heading' => $request->heading,
            'date' => $request->date,
            'location' => $request->location,
            'detail' => $request->detail,
            'image_gallery' => $value[$key] ?? [],
        ]);
    }
    return redirect()->route('site-management.events');
}
```

Comment: what inside `$request->image_gallery` .?  i think `'image_gallery' =>  $request->image_gallery[$key]`

Comment: request here https://ibb.co/v3ZKkyC please check it

Comment: Use implode function to make array to string. But in your code your image will be uploaded as tmp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your model use this

```
protected $casts = ['image_gallery'=>'array'];
```

because the value you are assigning is an array and your filed was expecting a string value. I hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

use

```php
foreach ($request->image_gallery as $key => $value) {

            SMEvent::create([
                'icon' => $request->icon,
                'heading' => $request->heading,
                'date' => $request->date,
                'location' => $request->location,
                'detail' => $request->detail,
                'image_gallery' => $request->image_gallery[$key][0] ?? [],
            ]);
        }
```

here `$request->image_gallery[$key]` it will give you loop array then `[0]` will return 1st data

Comment: @sta he is not uploading image i guess. it's already  uploaded only path he is try to add in database

Comment: image_galley has multiple image  when i insert multi image and then duplicate data is inserting

Comment: @ZubairMukhtar then use `updateOrCreate()`https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods